# Vue.js: The route change but its repective component is not rendered. No errors in the console

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the vue-router instance working, I mean when i click in a button router-link, the url goes to another address and i have in the router.js file, the right pairs “route” and component". but here comes the problem: the route change but the component is not rendered and there is no error in the console

**Component 1**

[image]

**Router.js**

[image]

**View-router**

[image]

Comment: leading dots in your router paths is not correct

Comment: Please, add code snippet in the post so it's easier for the community.